# Wikidata Query: How to retrieve the normal (non-verbose) JSON?

Tags: wikidata, sparql

We can download the results of a Wikidata Query as "JSON file" or "JSON file (verbose)"

Example link of random query: http://w.wiki/WQ.

I am developing a javascript software which retrieves some data from the Wikidata Query. But when I get the JSON, it is the same as the "JSON file (verbose)", but I really don't need/want all the other data that comes together.

Which argument should I pass in the URL to get the non-verbose JSON?

Comment: You can't download them. Simple JSON is generated from [full JSON](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-results-json/) in your browser using something like [this](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/plugins/gitiles/wikidata/query/gui/+/refs/heads/master/wikibase/queryService/api/Sparql.js#400).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a parameter to get this non-verbose data from the API, but you can simplify it using a lib such as [wikidata-sdk](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-sdk), more specifically the [`wdk.simplify.sparqlResults`](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-sdk/blob/master/docs/simplify_sparql_results.md) function